# C++ string to C char array for writing to binary file

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am trying to write and read string to/from binary file, but I can't understand why sizeof(t) returns 4.

```
//write to file
ofstream f1("example.bin", ios::binary | ios::out);
string s = "Valentin";
char* t = new char[s.length()+1];
strcpy(t, s.c_str());
cout << s.length()+1 << " " << sizeof(t) << endl; // prints 9 4
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(t); i++)
{
    //t[i] += 100;
}
f1.write(t, sizeof(t));
f1.close();

// read from file
ifstream f2("example.bin", ios::binary | ios::in);
while(f2)
{
    int8_t x;
    f2.read((char*)&x, 1);
    //x -= 100;
    cout << x;  //print Valee
}
cout << endl;
f2.close();
```

It doesn't matter what size I put in char* array t, code always prints "4" as its size. What must I do to write longer than 4 bytes of data?

Comment: `sizeof(t)` just gives you the size of a pointer, because that's what `t` is. If you want the size of the memory you allocated for `t`, why not do `s.length()+1` instead?

Comment: why all this aerobics with string to `char *` ? string has a `data()` and thats probably all you need

Comment: sizeof operator returns the static size of the *type*. It gets turned into a constant number at compile time (in C++ anyway, in C there is VLA). Size of pointer is usually 4 for 32 bit binaries, 8 for 64 bit binaries.

Comment: `sizeof(t)` -> `strlen(t)`. But consider the second comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to do the writing code the easy way

```
//write to file
ofstream f1("example.bin", ios::binary | ios::out);
string s = "Valentin";
f1.write(s.c_str(), s.size() + 1);
f1.close();
```

EDIT the OP actually wants something like this

```
#include <algorithm> // for transform

string s = "Valentin";
// copy s to t and add 100 to all bytes in t
string t = s;
transform(t.begin(), t.end(), t.begin(), [](char c) { return c + 100; });
// write to file
ofstream f1("example.bin", ios::binary | ios::out);
f1.write(t.c_str(), t.size() + 1);
f1.close();
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking to add to every char (which I believe is in ASCII dec number) some number (+100 in for loop in my code), so simple write(s.c_str() ...) won't do for me.

Comment: @user3007875 OK I missed that part of your code. It is a very odd thing to want to do though are you sure you got that right? You wouldn't be the first newbie to spend ages trying to solve the wrong problem. See edit to my answer for a version that does that as well.

Comment: Did you test your code from edited part? I copy pasted it and it throws error in transform line (no matching function call). Anyway,  it works with me original code (with for loop), so the problem is solved. I marked your answer as correct, thank you.

Comment: @user3007875 Did you have `#include <algorithm>`? If you did then try `std::transform` instead of `transform`.

Comment: I did. My whole code:
'''
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "Valentin";
    // copy s to t and add 100 to all bytes in t
    string t = s;
    ransform(t.begin(), t.end(), [](char c) { return c + 100; });
    // write to file
    ofstream f1("example.bin", ios::binary | ios::out);
    f1.write(t.c_str(), t.size() + 1);
    f1.close();
}
'''
Throws same error. Anyway, it doesn't really matter now, but thank you for your help.

Comment: @user3007875 `transform` not `ransform`

Comment: Sorry yes, I tried with std::transform and accidentaly deletede 't' as well. It's same error with "transform" though. I am guessing mingw doesnt support it.

Comment: @user3007875 transform has been part of standard C++ since the very first edition of the C++ standard (and used before that as well).

Comment: @user3007875 OK my mistake, see update. You are right I should test the code I write, my apologies

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(char*)` prints the size used by a pointer to (a) char(s). It's 4 on your platform.

If you need the size of the string, you should use `strlen`. Or, simply, `s.length()`.

Comment: Though those can differ if there are unaccounted for internal NULs.

Answer (score 2):

`char *t` is a pointer, not an array, so `sizeof` will return the size of a pointer on your machine, which is apparently 4 bytes.

The correct way to determine the length of a C-style string is to include `<cstring>` and use `std::strlen`.